# how to zoom d3.js chart and reload data with greater granularity (in AJAX)

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, d3.js, zooming

When I zoom my chart, I need replace some data by a new block of data (AJAX Query).

But I have problem to merge with original data without old point and **Update line path**

See [Zoom chart on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albanlopez/Egd2q/17/).

```
// Replace or add part of data
function zoom(g) {
   var data2add=[      // get new data by ajax query
      {"date":"2013-05-02T20:00","speed":0.878,"angle":269,"x":-0.725,"y":-0.018},
      ...
   ];
   console.log("data", data, "data2add", data2add);

data2add = data2add.map(function(d, i) {
                  return {
                      date:meanDate.call(data, d, i),
                      Speed:Speed.call(data, d, i),
                      angle:angle.call(data, d, i),
                      xSpeed:xSpeed.call(data, d, i),
                      ySpeed:ySpeed.call(data, d, i)
                  };
              });

 data = data.filter(function(element, index, array){
                    return (element.date<data2add[0].date || element.date > data2add[data2add.length-1].date);
                })
             .sort(function (a, b) {
                  return a.date - b.date;
                })
             .concat(data2add);       console.log("newData", data);


   d3.selectAll("path.line").data(data).enter();

   g.selectAll('circle').data(data).enter().append("circle")
     .attr("class", "dot");
   g.updateCurve()
    .drawAxis ();
}
```

Comment: If I have already loaded down all the data. Is there an easy way to only display a reduced sample of the data until the viewer zooms. More specifically, only ever display X number of data points intelligently at any one time. 

The problem is that the graph is becoming unresponsive when I plot all my data points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your use of `.concat()`. It merges the arrays without taking any points out. What you should do instead depends on what you're trying to do with the data. If you want to get rid of all of your old points, you can just overwrite `data` with `data2add`.

If you want to add your new data and then keep a certain range of your old data, you can use `.filter()` on your old array before `.concat()`. Just create a filtering function that checks to see if the element is both within your range and not equal to anything in the other array. This would look something like the following:

```
function filterFunction(value, i, thisArray){
    //Check to see if point is in range
    if(value < maxRange && value > minRange){

        //Note that you might have to change this depending on how 'equal' 
        //your elements are. You could also iterate through and check the dates, for
        //example.

        return (newDataArray.indexOf(value) > -1 ? 0 : 1)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok for filtering, http://jsfiddle.net/albanlopez/Egd2q/23/ but have you an idea for update line chart with new value ?

Comment: I'd recommend using the date as a data key and using the standard d3 enter/exit/update pattern to move things. I generally apply scales to set cx, cy, etc. and then transition to the new positions.

Answer (score 3):

for zoom and update line chart with include zoom data [exemple here](http://jsfiddle.net/albanlopez/Egd2q/30/):

1. filter old data for not include duplicate area
2. concat filtered data with zoom data
3. Sort New array of data dy date
4. rebuild serie  of dot
5. redraw curve dot and axis, but curve need draw like    `this.select("path.line").attr("d", line(data));` instead of `this.select("path.line").attr("d", line);`

for draw and redraw Attribute of line and Dots

```
 g.updateCurve = function(_){
    // Update the line path.
    this.select("path.line")
    .attr("d", line(_));

    // add each point
    this.selectAll('circle.dot')
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return xScale (d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return yScale (d.ySpeed); })
    .attr("r", function(d) {return rScale (d.xSpeed)*2; });

    return this;
};
```

for draw and redraw axxis

```
g.drawAxis = function(){
    // Update the x-axis.
    g.select(".x.axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + xPos + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    g.select(".y.axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
        .call(yAxis);
    return this;
};
```

for zoom and replace part of data

```
function zoom(g) {
   var data2add=[
      {"date":"2013-05-02T20:00","speed":0.878,"angle":269,"x":-0.725,"y":-0.018},
      ...
  ];

  data2add = data2add.map(function(d, i) {
                  return {
                      date:meanDate.call(data, d, i),
                      Speed:Speed.call(data, d, i),
                      angle:angle.call(data, d, i),
                      xSpeed:xSpeed.call(data, d, i),
                      ySpeed:ySpeed.call(data, d, i)
                  };
              });

  mergedata = data.filter(function(element, index, array){
      return (element.date<data2add[0].date || element.date>data2add[data2add.length-1].date);
  })
  .concat(data2add)
  .sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.date-b.date;
  });
  // .sortBy( function(){ return this.date } ); // http://phrogz.net/JS/Array.prototype.sortBy.js

  var newDots = g.selectAll('circle')
                 // define new [data]
                 .data(mergedata, function(d) { return d.date; });
  newDots.exit().remove(); // exit() content the deprecated points, remove it
  newDots.enter().append("circle")// enter() content the new points, draw it
   .attr("class", "dot");

    g.updateCurve()
     .drawAxis ();
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up that the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/albanlopez/Egd2q/30/) is buggy in that the line jumps around.